# Spring Data JPA Repository returns Object[] instead of MyType while using Sum Function

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, jpql, spring-data-jpa

Until today I was using this statement:

```
@Query(value = "select top 5 p.*, sum(po.quantity) as total_quantity from product p " +
        "inner join productorder po " +
            "on p.id = po.product_id " +
        "group by p.id, p.name " +
        "order by total_quantity desc", nativeQuery = true)
List<Product> findTopFiveBestSellerNative();
```

Here as i define the return type as a list of Products, i exactly get what i need. And the selected column total_quantity is simply ignored.

Lastly i needed to integrate pagination into this query. Since Spring does not support pagination handling with native queries, i wanted to first transform this query to JPQL (then i will add pagination). And now it looks like this:

```
@Query(value = "select p, sum(po.quantity) as total_quantity " + 
        "from Product p, ProductOrder po " +
        "where p.id = po.pk.product " +
        "group by p.id, p.name " +
        "order by total_quantity desc")
List<Product> findTopFiveBestSeller();
```

The return type is now a list of object arrays, where the first element of array is Product, and second one is the total_quantity. (Although the method signature says List..)

How can i change my statement or somehow achieve this, so that i do not have to deal with array, and simply just get my Product objects?

EDIT: I had the idea to use this query as a subquery, and just select the products from the subquery. It turns out that the JPQL cannot do subqueries in the 'from' clause..

Comment: I would simply replace "Product" with "Object". Object will handle everything in my thought.

Comment: It is not that simple. Firstly it is an object array. So i have to iterate through the list of object[], and get the first element, cast it to Product, put in a new list, in order to use that as a product list.. Secondly, when i pass the pageable attribute (which was my actual goal), the return type is Page. So i have to iterate through object arrays in the page, get the first element again, at the end i have to initialize my own page, assigning every spring page attribute (size, sort, direction etc.) separately, so that at the end i can have a Page<Product> which i can use seamlessly

Answer (score 0):

Fact is your query is not returning only the columns needed to build a Product object, so Spring JPA is mapping it to an object.

Create an aggregate entity that extends product and that contains the property totalQuantity and map your query to it (possibly in another repository)

Comment: My first query (Native one) is also not returning only the columns needed to build a Product object, but the same Spring JPA is mapping it to an object (Product)....  Is this behaviour just for JPQL specific?

Comment: akcasoy . Please see this - http://cfmtips.blogspot.com/2016/08/spring-jpa-repository-hibernate.html. Hope it would help you...